# Sort the contents of an NSScrollView, NSTableView, using Binding in ArrayController

Tags: objective-c, binding, nsarraycontroller, nsscrollview, nssortdescriptor

I have an `NSScrollView` wich is bound with an `ArrayController`. I need to sort the content alphabetically. I've tried to do this with bindings but I can't find the right thing to bind. I used the following `sortDescriptor` on my `ArrayController`.

```
[myArrayController setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"myKey" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)]]];
```

Do I miss a step in the process or am I not even close to sorting the content?

Comment: Please check this [project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5462248/arraycontrollersortsearch-zip-58k?da=y)...which uses array controller and does searching and sorting. Without much codes, uses Bindings.

Comment: i have updated the question so that this question will be shown on Binding as well as ArrayController keywords

Answer (score 0):

Did you try FilterPredicate ? this is a sample code:

```
NSDate *afterDate=[balanceDateAfter objectValue];
NSDate *beforeDate=[balanceDateBefore  objectValue];
NSComparisonResult duration=[beforeDate timeIntervalSinceDate:afterDate];

duration=duration/3600;
duration=duration/24;

[checkInBalanceArray setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(checkDate >= %@) AND (checkDate <= %@)", afterDate, beforeDate]];

[checkOutBalanceArray setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(checkDate >= %@) AND (checkDate <= %@)", afterDate, beforeDate]];
```

Comment: Maybe it works, but I'm lookin' for a solution with bindings instead of a predicate code solution, but thank you for your answer.