# Binding search field and table view in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, tableview

I have a nstableview. I would like to filter the results based on the characters entered in a search bar in OSX. So how do i bind the table view and the search field in OSX not in IOS? :) Thanks.

Comment: +1 for nice question on mac osx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a [project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5462248/arraycontrollersortsearch-zip-58k?da=y) that you can download and look how it works.

The steps are as :

1. Drag NSArrayController, set all bindings with this. Create  NSSearchField.
2. In binding inspector, Search "Bind to ArrayController".
3. Set Controller Key to "filterPredicate".
4. Set Predicate Format to "property1 contains $value" If you want a single search field to search on multiple values(say 3) use || as : "property1 contains $value || property2 contains $value || property3 contains $value"

Also, this [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253391/sort-the-contents-of-an-nsscrollview-nstableview-using-binding-in-arraycontrol).

Comment: Not yet AKV. i couldn't download the project. There is some problem in net here.

Comment: Few steps to do, check if this helps

Comment: this is a great example. thanks a ton! one small fix: click the search field, go into bindings>search>predicate>format and replace the last salary with name.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya the project link is broken... could you please fix it or better put it on github? much appreciated! :)