# What does "key contains $value" mean?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nssearchfield

I have an `NSSearchField` bound to an `NSDictionaryController`. In my search field's predicate format, I have a code like this `key contains $value` and what does it mean? What other alternatives are there for the predicate format (lines of code)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A quick [search of the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=predicate+format) turns up [this chapter in the Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html):

> Variables are denoted with a `$` (for example `$VARIABLE_NAME`).

I don't see anywhere where it's explicitly mentioned, but the implication is that identifiers *not* prefixed by a `$` are treated as keys—i.e., retrieved by [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/). The predicate will match those objects from the dictionary controller whose [value for](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKey%3a) `key` …

> `CONTAINS`
>
> The left-hand expression contains the right-hand expression.

… *contains* the value of `$value`.

So what's `$value`, then? [The Cocoa Bindings Reference explains](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/Concepts/BindingTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002305-216985):

> The multiple-value predicate binding allows you to create a search field pop-up menu that is pre populated with menu items that correspond to predicate filters. Each of the predicate bindings correspond to an entry in the search field pop-up menu. This multiple-value binding is used by the NSSearchField predicate binding.
>
> The display name string is used as the menu item title. The predicate format is string that specifies the predicate for that menu item using the predicate format described in Predicate Programming Guide. **Any occurrences of the string `$value` in the predicate format string are replaced with the contents of the search field.**

In other words, an NSSearchField predefines the variable `value` for its predicates as holding whatever text is currently in the field—i.e., the text the user is searching for.

So, for example, if you create a predicate with the format `name contains $value`, and the user searches for “Emily”, that predicate will match those objects whose `name` contains (as a substring) the string “Emily”.

Comment: Then if I have a dictionary with Keys : One, Two Three. And the string values are : 1,2,3. And I want to search it that when I type"1", the search results show the object 1 and its key? How do I search for the dictionary value instead of its key?

Comment: In a simpler way of saying, how do bind the Predicate Format so that I can search for the "value" instead of searching the "key"? Thank!

Answer (score 2):

`key` stands for the Key of the dictionary and `$value` stands for the entered value in the `NSSearchField`.

For searching from more fields you can use || and && in the Predicate Format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274870/cocoa-binding-mutable-dictionary-with-search-field

Comment: then what if i want to search for the Value of the dictionary?

Comment: Then bind the table with key and value to two columns and use || in predicte format.

Comment: Sorry, but can you show an example? Is it like" || contains $value"? OR "key||value contains $value"?

Comment: I dont have mac with me, I can show you tomorrow. Now finding my own answer in SO.

Comment: Check here if this contains || in predicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253391/sort-the-contents-of-an-nsscrollview-nstableview-using-binding-in-arraycontrol

Answer (score 0):

I somehow found out!
I for the predicate format, I just need to type

```
value contains $value
```

for it to work. Now I understand! Thank you all for your help!!!

Answer (score -3):

```
foreach (var item in dictionary) {
   cellValue.Text = item.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I feel like this answer was meant for a monotouch question